# How to save or share slideshow in iOS 9.3.2?

Tags: ios, photos.app, iphone

I can play slideshow in my iPhone with Photos app but I cannot save or share that slideshow. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to save or share a slideshow. The only output is to the device screen itself or over AirPlay.